# Passing a function that returns data to react native FlatList data property

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, setstate, asyncstorage

I used the following function inside the Flatlist data property but it is not rendering anything. why? I think an alternative is to set state inside the function and use the state as the flatlist data property, but in that case how do I set state whenever asyncstorage changes?

```
async function getFlatlistData(){
      try{
        const numbers = await AsyncStorage.getAllKeys();
        //numbers = 
        // ["{\"key\":\"1678328476308\",\"title\":\"Dog\"}",
        //"{\"key\":\"1678328921886\",\"title\":\"Cat\"}"]
        
  
        numbers.forEach(function myFunction(item, index, arr) {
                          arr[index] = JSON.parse(item);
                          arr[index]['key'] = Number(arr[index]['key'])
                        })
        numbers.sort((a, b) => b.key - a.key);
        console.log("running")
        return numbers

      } catch (error) {
        alert(error)
      }
      
    }
```

```
return (
    </View>
       <FlatList 
          data={getFlatlistData()} 
          renderItem={
            ({item}) => <Text>{item.title}</Text>
          } 
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
       />
     </View>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

The FlatList component is not rendering anything because it is receiving a promise instead of an array of data.

You need to use a useState to get the array before assigning to the Flatlist.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { FlatList, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';

function App() {
 const [data, setData] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
  async function fetchData() {
    try {
     const numbers = await AsyncStorage.getAllKeys();
     const parsedNumbers = numbers.map((item) => JSON.parse(item));
     const sortedNumbers = parsedNumbers.sort((a, b) => b.key - a.key);
     setData(sortedNumbers);
   } catch (error) {
    alert(error);
  }
}

fetchData();
}, []);

return (
 <View>
  <FlatList
    data={data}
    renderItem={({ item }) => <Text>{item.title}</Text>}
    keyExtractor={(item) => item.key.toString()}
  />
</View>
);
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

First: You need to use useState hook to render the components.
Second: Your async function returns promise, not an array.

```
import React from 'react';
import { FlatList, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';

export default function FlatListData() {

    const [data, setData] = React.useState([]);

    const getFlatlistData = async() => {
        try{
            const numbers = await AsyncStorage.getAllKeys();
            if(numbers){
                const newArr = [...JSON.parse(numbers)];
                newArr.map((obj) => {
                    obj.key = Number(obj.key);
                });
                newArr.sort((a, b) => b.key - a.key);
                setData(newArr);
            }
        }catch(e){
            throw e;
        }
    }

    React.useEffect(() => {
        getFlatlistData();
    }, []);

    return (

        <FlatList
        data={data} 
        renderItem={({item}) => <Text>{item.title}</Text>} 
        keyExtractor={(i, x) => x}/>

    );

}
```